# How to read sample records parquet file in S3?

Tags: python-3.x, parquet

I have 100s of parquet files in S3, I want to check whether all the parquet files are created properly or not. Basically the downstream system should able to read these parquet files without any issue. Before downstream system read these files, I want my python scripts to read the sample, 10 records for each parquet files.
I using the below syntax to read the parquet file:

```
import pandas as pd
from boto3 import client

conn = client('s3') 
buffer = io.BytesIO() 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

result = s3.get_object(Bucket="my bucket", Key="my file location")
text = result["Body"].read().decode()
```

Need your input to read sample records, not all the records from parquet file. Thank you.

Comment: It's not super easy to do this right now. I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3705